# ValueError: The elements are 0-sized

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, text-files

Haven't been able to find any information on the web about this problem.  I'm trying to read from a text file using numpy.

```
data = np.fromfile("C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\elements.txt",dtype=str,count=-1,sep=' ')
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
ValueError: The elements are 0-sized.
```

I've never seen this error before, and a Google search didn't return any information about this error.  Why is this error occurring, and how can I get around it?

EDIT: Here is an excerpt from the text file

```
1   Hydrogen 1.008      
2   Helium  4.002602
3   Lithium 6.94    
4   Beryllium 9.0121831
5   Boron 10.81 
6   Carbon 12.011
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c) might help. Some source code. `if (dtype->elsize == 0)` seems to be your enemy

Comment: Thanks, I see that now.  I'm not sure what it actually means though, or how to fix it.

Comment: Try `data = np.genfromtxt("C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\elements.txt", dtype=None)` or `dtype=str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably better off using `np.genfromtxt` for text files; `np.fromfile` is better for binary files.

This gives the string array you originally seemed to be going for:

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('tmp.txt', dtype=str)
array([['1', 'Hydrogen', '1.008'],
       ['2', 'Helium', '4.002602'],
       ['3', 'Lithium', '6.94'],
       ['4', 'Beryllium', '9.0121831'],
       ['5', 'Boron', '10.81'],
       ['6', 'Carbon', '12.011']], 
      dtype='|S9')
```

And this gives you a record array that has flexible dtype:

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('tmp.txt', dtype=None)
array([(1, 'Hydrogen', 1.008), (2, 'Helium', 4.002602),
       (3, 'Lithium', 6.94), (4, 'Beryllium', 9.0121831),
       (5, 'Boron', 10.81), (6, 'Carbon', 12.011)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', 'S9'), ('f2', '<f8')])
```

But this is what I would do, using `unpack` allows you to assign to several variables:

```
>>> n, name, mass = np.genfromtxt('tmp.txt', dtype='S', unpack=True)
>>> n = n.astype(int)
>>> mass = mass.astype(float)
```